# Vectorizing range setting - MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

I have got the following code. I need to rewrite it without looping. How should I do it?

```
l1 = [1 2 3 2 1];
l2 = [3 4 4 5 4];
A = zeros(5,5);
for i=1:5
    A(i, l1(i):l2(i)) = 1;
end

A
```

Comment: Why do you need to rewrite it? Is it too slow?

Comment: :D you know, if you word the correctly, this is actually a good question

Comment: @Jørgen Yes, it is slow. Actually matrix size is huge and I have several operations similar to the above one. This is just an example and it is simplified as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
I = 1:5 % Array corresponding to iterator : "for i=1:5"
out = bsxfun(@le,l1(:),I) & bsxfun(@ge,l2(:),I)
```

If you need a double datatype array, convert to double, like so -

```
out_double = double(out)
```

Comment: Nice, to see that you don't need the full coordinate grid, as bsxfun will expand 1:5 automatically. Note that this answer does return a logical (which may be a good thing, but is not identical to the loop).

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Edited solution to cover that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Add one more into the mix then! This one simply uses a cumsum to generate all the 1s - so it does not use the `:` operator at all - It's also fully parallel :D

```
l1 = [1 2 3 2 1];
l2 = [3 4 4 5 4];
A = zeros(5,5);

L1 = l1+(1:5)*5-5; %Convert to matrix location index
L2 = l2+(1:5)*5-5; %Convert to matrix location index
A(L1) = 1;         %Place 1 in that location
A(L2) = 1;         %Place 1 in that location

B = cumsum(A,1) ==1 ;   %So fast
Answer = (A|B)';        %Lightning fast

Answer =

 1     1     1     0     0
 0     1     1     1     0
 0     0     1     1     0
 0     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could build the matrix without using a loop.

```
% Our starting values
l1 = [1 2 3 2 1];
l2 = [3 4 4 5 4];

% Coordinate grid of the right size (we don't need r, but I keep it there for illustration)
[r,c] = ndgrid(1:5);

% Build the logical index based on our lower and upper bounds on the column indices
idx_l1=bsxfun(@ge,c,l1');
idx_l2=bsxfun(@le,c,l2');

% The result
A = zeros(size(idx_l1));
A(idx_l1&idx_l2)=1
```

You may need something like `[r,c] = ndgrid(1:numel(l1),1:10)`.

Also if your matrix size is truly huge and memory becomes an issue, you may want to stick to a loop anyway, but for 'normal size' this could be faster.

Answer (score 0):

There should be some skepticism in every vectorization. If you measure the time actually your loop is faster than the given answers, mostly because you only perform in place write.

Here is another one that would probably get faster for larger sizes but I haven't tested:

```
tic
myind = [];
for i = 1:5
    myind = [myind (5*(i-1))+[l1(i):l2(i)]];
end
A(myind) = 1;
toc
```

gives the transposed `A` because of the linear indexing order.